# Windows Forms Host + System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Chart

Tags: wpf, charts

Good day all

I have the following question:

I would like to use Chart from Windows Forms due to the fact that it allows to build much more types of graphical visualisation that one from WPF Toolkit does.

So, I am adding Chart control for Windows Forms as a child element into the WindowsFormsHost. But, when I run the application I and all my clients see only white area. Though, any other Windows Forms Control works great in Windows Forms Host.

What is wrong with the Chart control?

Here is the XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:wfi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
xmlns:CHR="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization"       
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
<wfi:WindowsFormsHost x:Name="mainFGrid" >
<CHR:Chart x:Name="mainChart" />
</wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Kind regards,

```
                   Anatoliy Sova
```

Comment: Do you think is this something to do with the .Net Framework 3.5 sp1? Please let me know if you find any solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found kind of Workaround, basically create the chart at runtime

http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1331

Thanks

Shaik

Comment: Thanks Shaik. Works a treat. it stretches and everything!